# i can't figure out why i keep getting this parser error

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.13;

contract WorkingWithVariables {
    uint256 public myUint
    
    function setMyUint(uint_myUint) public {
        myUint = _myUint;
    }
    
    bool public mybool;
    
    function setMyBool(bool_myBool) public {
        myBool = _myBool;
    }
}
```

line 6

ParserError: Expected ‘;’ but got ‘function’
Function setmyuint (uint_myuint) public {
^_ ____ ^

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very low-quality question with no real contribution. You're missing a space between parameter type and parameter name on each one of these functions, you're missing a semicolon after `uint256 public myUint`, and you've written `mybool` with a lower-case b in some cases and with a higher-case B in other cases. The code is simply too sloppy. You should be more meticulous!

Comment: thank you goodvibrator i mean @goodvibration , you're right its fixed now. this code was from a course im doing because ya know im a brand new programmer. you can close if you want idc.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity requires lines to end in a semicolon. Simply change this line:

```
    uint256 public myUint
```

to this

```
    uint256 public myUint;
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're highly appreciated